Signal Integrity Issue with Polygons as Ground in Altium Designer
I’m performing a signal integrity analysis on a 6-layer PCB and noticed that when the inner layers are ground planes, the analysis is correct, with impedances around 50 ohms in general, 90 ohms for USB, etc., as per the design.
However, if instead of using planes I use signal layers with polygons (which physically represent the same thing) while keeping the same clearances and assigning the "supply net" parameter to 0V in the schematic, the resulting impedances are extremely high, around 200 ohms or other absurd values. It’s as if the tool isn’t recognizing that polygon as a ground plane, even though it is.
I might be missing a step to explicitly tell Altium that this polygon is “ground.” So far, I’ve only managed to define it using the "supply net" parameter and connecting the power port to GND. Can anyone help or suggest if something else needs to be configured?

When doing a impedance calculation, do you need to set up a reference, since you don't have it as a power plane?  Even though you've assigned the polygon to the 0V net, maybe it needs to know to use that as the reference?

I’m not sure what else to do. It must be an issue where it doesn’t "know" that the polygon is ground, even though the signal is set to 0V. There must be some other option or configuration to specify it, but I can’t figure out which one, despite searching everywhere. It might even be a bug.
